# How do i correctly communicate with a ftdi f232rl module via python?

Tags: python, pyserial, ftdi

I'm currently trying to communicate with a FTDI R232RL chip through pyserial which itself is connected to a small stepper motor. The driver I am using is the FTDI VCP driver. Through PuTTY you are able to connect to the chip by only selecting the correct COM port and baudrate. Via xterm you can then send a string to the chip (e.g. pos 2600, pos 1500 ,*rst (for resetting)) to move the stepper motor to a new position. This works, but i want to use a python script to send these strings to the ftdi chip.

I've currently tried to use the pyserial package to communicate with the chip, which works to a certain degree. It tells me which port is open/ which port the chip is plugged in but none of the usual commands for the chip seem to work. So far there are no errors sent back which could give any hint on what is going wrong.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial(
  port='COM3',
  baudrate=115200,
  parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
  bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
ser.write(b'*rst') 
ser.close() `
```

This is the code i used from the pyserial documentation page.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: When using the device through PuTTY, do you have to hit the Enter key to execute commands?  If so, you need to terminate commands in your Python code with a `\r` and/or `\n` character.

Comment: what are the settings which work with xterm/putty? PARITY_ODD is rather ODD - maybe you need to select PARITY_NONE.

Comment: Just tested your code and it worked on my FTDI FT232RL

Answer (score -1):

I worked a couple of years ago with such system and I will try to help with info out of my head.

I did not read the datasheet of the chip and I am not entirely sure whether it supports 115200 baudrate so, just to "play on the safe side" I use 9600 in this example. (This is something you have to check, having a configuration mismatch will lead to wrong communication obviously).

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baud=9600, timeout=1)  # timeouts are important!
ser.open()  # THIS STEP IS MISSING IN YOUR QUESTION
ser.write(<your bytes>)
response = ser.readline()
# maybe decode to human readable format? response.decode('ascii')
ser.close()
ser.port = None
```

Additional tip: here you know by some other means that your chip is connected on `COM3`. What if it doesn't? You might want to implement a routine to figure out where and if the chip is connected at some port by `try`ing (`try/except`) some dummy communication on all ports available and select the one where it asserts.

Comment: Other tip: When I need to select the right port, I usually reprogram the EEPROM of the FTDI chip (with FT_PROG) and I change the description of the FTDI chip. Then you can list all the available port with  `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` and get the port description for all of them, I just pick the description that match with the one that I've set on the chip.